# Why doesn't Fleming's "Right hand rule" apply to this?

Tags: electromagnetism, electricity

[image]I've wound a metal/glass toroid coil and operated this configuration. I've only produced millivolts and it's erratic producing ac. It's probably obvious to most but I can't figure it out. I'm wondering if the core saturates and the flux jumps or bulges outside the windings causing a reverse or opposing current.
According to Flemings right hand rule it should work...but it doesn't.
Thanks.[image]

Comment: Have you tried the measurement without the iron core?

Comment: your iron core, is a block or a full ring/toroid?  how are you rotating it?

Comment: It appears that due to the symmetry, there is no net magnetic flux through the coil...?

Comment: I only used my illustration to show the principal. I used a laminated toroid coil. The coil is actually stationary with the magnetic field rotating around the coil.

Comment: Why do you have two north poles facing each other?

Comment: Because the rotating magnetic field in the same direction with a N to N should cause current flow. If N to S would cancel out. I have tried N to S with rotating S in opposite direction of N but still just millivolts in jerky DC & AC. Also tried putting 12 volts DC into coil but no motoring effect which I expected sense the flux from the winding would lock into the core & not react with the magnetic field of the magnet.

Comment: To the question of measuring without the iron core...no...I need the iron core to attract the two north fields together cutting the windings.